# How to position a <span>&#9776;</span> element

Tags: html, css

How do I position this element, using the unicode for `&#9776;` I have it within a `<span>` tag with a `<div>` with an `id` of `main`, however I am unable to move this element within the web page at all.

Any help would be appreciated thanks; the icon is serving as my menu button.

Comment: How did you attempt to position the element? Can you show your "*[mcve]*" code so that we can reproduce your problem, and then provide a practicable answer?

Comment: Hi Luke. It's hard to see what exact issue you are having here, but there are lots of questions about positioning on stackoverflow. I've linked a few above for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move inline display type elements (that is span's by default). Change `span` to `div` or set `display:block`; You can move your outer div block. You need to remember that it is good to set parent node position property to "`relative`".